# Can't find any tables after psql dump import from pgexercises.com

Tags: postgresql, import

I'm trying to import the database used for the PostgreSQL exercises at [pgexercises.com](http://pgexercises.com).

I ran the following command as recommended, and it went through without errors and even showing Inserts with the right number of rows:

```
psql -U cornelius -f clubdata.sql -d postgres -x
```

I can connect to the database created with `psql exercises`. However, I get `Did not find any relations` with `\dt`.

When rerunning the import command, I get errors saying that the tables already exist.

**What's going on? Where are my tables?**

Here's a subset of the dump file:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--
CREATE DATABASE exercises;
\c exercises
CREATE SCHEMA cd;

-- Dumped from database version 9.2.0
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.2.0
-- Started on 2013-05-19 16:05:10 BST

SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;

--
-- TOC entry 7 (class 2615 OID 32769)
-- Name: cd; Type: SCHEMA; Schema: -; Owner: -
--

SET search_path = cd, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- TOC entry 171 (class 1259 OID 32818)
-- Name: bookings; Type: TABLE; Schema: cd; Owner: -; Tablespace:
--

CREATE TABLE bookings (
    bookid integer NOT NULL,
    facid integer NOT NULL,
    memid integer NOT NULL,
    starttime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    slots integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO bookings (bookid, facid, memid, starttime, slots) VALUES
(0, 3, 1, '2012-07-03 11:00:00', 2),
(1, 4, 1, '2012-07-03 08:00:00', 2),
(2, 6, 0, '2012-07-03 18:00:00', 2),
(3, 7, 1, '2012-07-03 19:00:00', 2),
(4, 8, 1, '2012-07-03 10:00:00', 1),
(5, 8, 1, '2012-07-03 15:00:00', 1),
(6, 0, 2, '2012-07-04 09:00:00', 3),
(7, 0, 2, '2012-07-04 15:00:00', 3),
(8, 4, 3, '2012-07-04 13:30:00', 2),
(9, 4, 0, '2012-07-04 15:00:00', 2);

--
-- TOC entry 2196 (class 2606 OID 32822)
-- Name: bookings_pk; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: cd; Owner: -; Tablespace:
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY bookings
    ADD CONSTRAINT bookings_pk PRIMARY KEY (bookid);

CREATE INDEX "bookings.memid_facid"
  ON cd.bookings
  USING btree
  (memid, facid);

ANALYZE;
```

Comment: The `psql` command line you used makes me think they were created in the database `postgres` -- but that shouldn't be possible, I think (ordinary users don't have permissions  to create objects there). But can you check there -- `psql postgres` ?

Comment: @Colin'tHart That turns out to be just so that the connection works, I think. The first line is to create a database "exercises".

Answer (score 3):

The solution is: **Schemas**, SQL for namespace.

The third line in the exercise dump is: `CREATE SCHEMA cd;`

As a result, the tables are accessible by prepending `cd.` in front of table names.

Running `\dt *` with wildcard also shows all tables present, no matter the namespace. This is a good thing to run when `\dt` gives no result even though one expects that it should have.